# JSON and VB.net

Tags: vb.net, json

I've got a small utility I use to communicate with Yahoo's APIs. Their servers return all the responses in JSON.

Is there an easy way to parse this into its base form when you don't necessarily know what will be in the response?

```
{
    "sessionId": "A.bpAsPs3RPYF0nUuAnCtuEUJMOmDDHbjZG5", 
    "primaryLoginId": "prometheussoft", 
    "displayInfo": {
        "avatarPreference": "2", 
        "checksum": "-1484747745"
    }, 
    "server": "rcore1.messenger.yahooapis.com", 
    "notifyServer": "rproxy1.messenger.yahooapis.com", 
    "constants": {
        "presenceSubscriptionsMaxPerRequest": 60
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can deserialize it to a dictionary with string parsing, any values that are objects can be done the same way with a nested dictionary.

However to get typing on the values you will need to at least know what is expected for each property